# How to declare and initialize variables in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm working in company as web developer as fresher  and example solutions online and I can make sense of most of the code but I'm not entirely sure what this line does.

`var $hello = $('<div class=newHello></div>');`
I'm assuming that it creates a jQuery variable with the value set to a blank  with the class of hello , but I want to be certain and also understand the syntax.

Why does a dollar sign precede the variable value? I know dollar signs are used in jQuery

give me some best example to understand this concept

Comment: Duplicate of [how to define variable in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418613/how-to-define-variable-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

That is just another variable, maybe the previous developer was a php developer, or just to difference which variables are jquery variables instead of other variables (such as using underscore before a variable to tell is a constant variable)

Answer (score 0):

when you use $ prefix variable initialization then this type of variable stores a jquery Object. like as $hello holds jquery Object